# Recursive methods - Ruler tick marks

Tags: java, methods, recursion

Today im working on a recursive method to place the tick marks on a ruler. The assignment says to place the tick marks and print its height and position. Assuming x & y as (0,0), a width of 20 and height of 10, the program should display something like

 Middle tick mark  - Position 10, height 10

 Position 5, height 5

 Position 2.5, height 2.5

 Position 7.5, height 2.5

 Position 15.0, height 5.0

 Position 12.5, height 2.5

 Position 17.5, height 2.5

 
Note the smallest height allowed is 2.00, and each position is half the height of the larger one. I tried a lot of stuff and I kind of have the idea, but is not working. I get the numbers from position 10 to 7.5, but the right side is a mess even though is just moving the x coordinate. This is my code, hope you can help me and thank you.

```
*main method contains the input for user and the method calls.
        DrawRulerLeft(x,y,width,height);     //Method to draw left part of rule
        DrawRulerRight(x,y,width,height);   //Method to draw right part of rule

public static void DrawRulerLeft(double x, double y, double w, double h) {

  if (h > 2 ) {  //smallest height aloud
        w = w/2;  
        System.out.println("Tick position:+ w + " Tick height: " + h );
        DrawRulerLeft(x, y, w, h/2);
 } 
 }

//Recursive method to draw right of rule
 public static void DrawRulerRight(double x, double y, double w, double h) {

     if (h > 2 && w >= 0) {
        DrawRulerRight(x+w/2,y,w/2,h/2); 
        System.out.println("Tick position:" + x + " Tick height: " + h );
         }

    }
```

Comment: I have not tested your code but know that you will need to call both methods from within both methods. In other words, `drawRulerLeft(...)` will need to call both `drawRulerLeft(...)` *and* `drawRulerRight(...)`, and same for `drawRulerRight(...)`. Also note that method names should begin with lower case letters and code formatting is important and should not be taken for granted (as you're doing).

Comment: The reason for having a left and right method is not clear. Why couldn't one recursive function handle both those sub-problems

Comment: @clwhisk yes I actually thought about using just one recursive function, but i dont know, I made a mess when I tried it so I decided to create two methods instead

Comment: Go with one, and please do not ignore code formatting when you do this. If not it will cause you to mess up, or if not that, will frustrate those you ask to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just need to factor in that any time there is a division of the ruler there is both a + and a - permutation. Ignore the left side/right side of the ruler paradigm because there is only a left side/right side of each division.

```
drawTicks(20, 20, 20);

public static void drawTicks(double h, double tick, double pos) {

    System.out.println("tick: " + tick + " pos: " + pos);

    if (tick / 2 >= 2) {

        if (tick != h) {
            drawTicks(h, tick / 2, pos + tick / 2);
        }

        drawTicks(h, tick / 2, pos - tick / 2);
    }

}
```

Outputs the following:

```
tick: 20.0 pos: 20.0
tick: 10.0 pos: 10.0
tick: 5.0 pos: 15.0
tick: 2.5 pos: 17.5
tick: 2.5 pos: 12.5
tick: 5.0 pos: 5.0
tick: 2.5 pos: 7.5
tick: 2.5 pos: 2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Akin to binary traversal on both halves, try this approach:-

```
//Recursive method to draw 
private static void DrawRulerRecursive(double w, double h) {
  if (h > 2) {
    System.out.println("Tick position:" + w + " Tick height: " + h);
    DrawRuler(w+w/2,h/2);
    DrawRuler(w-w/2,h/2);
  }
}

public static void DrawRuler(int w, int h) {
   double mid = (0 + w)/2; // Range: (0:20), Mid: 10
   DrawRulerRecursive(mid, h);
}
```

The problem is similar to building a BST where the height of `tick` is halved while going down a level. My suggestion is a depth-first in-order traversal but you could also use breadth-first traversal.

Answer (score 1):

The basic operation is drawing a tick of height `height` in the middle of the interval. Now `x` and `y` and `width` weren't defined and this was homework so I'll just use a different notation. Say the interval given is `(a, b)`

So the method signature can be `void drawTick(double a, double b, double height)`.

The first line of the method can test the base case, which has to do with height being at least 2. No infinity of recursive calls, thank you!

```
if(height < 2) return;
```

The next line can 'draw' the tick.

```
System.out.println("Tick position:"+ (a+b)/2 + " Tick height: " + height );
```

Now from this setup you may figure out what needs to be done next to draw all the ticks of half that height.